# Apex and Visualforce Page - Data Display in Page

Tags: salesforce, apex, apex-code, visualforce, salesforce-lightning

My Data displays the list results as grouped but does not create a singular display for the same value.

I would like the returned Data to Show everything grouped into a single column header...let me share the code.

To elaborate :

```
public Summary[] Summaries { get; set; }   
public Alphabet() {

AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [select A,Sum(B)Currency,C from D WHERE A != null AND C < LAST_FISCAL_QUARTER GROUP BY A,C ORDER BY A limit 1000];

Summaries = new List<Summary>();
     for (AggregateResult ar : groupedResults) {
             Summaries.add(new Summary(ar));
                 }
   }

   public class Summary {
       public String A{ get; private set; }
      public Decimal B{ get; private set; }
    public Date C{ get; private set; }



    public Summary(AggregateResult ar) {
          A= (String) ar.get('A');
        B= (Decimal) ar.get('B');
          C=  (Date) ar.get('C');

     } 


}  



 }
```

My Page :

```
<apex:page controller="Alphabet">    

<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock > 

 <apex:pageBlockTable value="{! Summaries}" var="s">

     <apex:column value="{! s.A}"/>
   <apex:column value="{! s.B}"/>

  </apex:pageBlockTable>      
   </apex:pageBlock>   
  </apex:form>  
 </apex:page>
```

My Display :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLRI8.png)

But I would like it to look like this :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXRIJ.png)

I deally I would like all th A1 values summed up together and not showing multiple A1's.

Please assist.